# Interval syntax for month and year in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=886414e39d28c1c2e91e43435d70e37b)**

```
CREATE TABLE PaL (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO PaL
(event_date)
VALUES 

('2020-01-01'),
('2020-02-05'),
('2020-03-20'),
('2020-04-15'),
('2020-05-11'),
('2020-06-18'),
('2020-07-19'),
('2020-12-31');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
iv_day_event_date     |   iv_month_event_date  |   iv_day_specific_date  |  iv_month_specific_date
----------------------|------------------------|-------------------------|---------------
2020-01-02            |    2019-12-01          |    2021-08-13           |     2021-07-12
2020-02-06            |    2020-01-05          |    2021-08-13           |     2021-07-12
2020-03-21            |    2020-02-20          |    2021-08-13           |     2021-07-12
2020-04-16            |    2020-03-15          |    2021-08-13           |     2021-07-12
2020-05-12            |    2020-04-11          |    2021-08-13           |     2021-07-12
2020-06-19            |    2020-05-18          |    2021-08-13           |     2021-07-12
2020-07-20            |    2020-06-19          |    2021-08-13           |     2021-07-12
2021-01-01            |    2020-11-30          |    2021-08-13           |     2021-07-12
```

---

I use the below query to get the interval for 1 day and 1 month:

```
SELECT 
(pl.event_date + interval '1 day')::date AS iv_day_event_date,
(pl.event_date - interval '1 month')::date AS iv_month_event_date,
(date '2021-08-12 18:37:19' + interval '1 day')::date AS iv_day_specific_date,
(date '2021-08-12 18:37:19' - interval '1 month')::date AS iv_month_specific_date
FROM PaL pl
```

---

This query works without any issue in `PostgresSQL`. 
However, when I run it on `redshift` I get an error on the interval for the month.

[image]

How do I need to modify the interval for the month to make it work in redshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `add_months()` or `dateadd()` instead:

```
ADD_MONTHS(pl.event_date, -1) AS iv_month_event_date
DATEADD(month, 1, pl.event_date)
```

The only caution is how these handle "end-of-month" dates.  I assume the difference is aligned with how the functions work in their respective "original" databases.

Who knows why Redshift did only half an implementation of `INTERVAL` arithmetic and then added Oracle and SQL Server functions to boot.